# How to stop webDriver in backgroundWorker with Stop button with this code?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, backgroundworker

I now learning backgroundWorker with Selenium and my goal is to integrate webdriver.Close();  and  webDriver.Quit() on click button STOP, following code work, but when I try to integrate webDriver.Quit() with STOP button it shows me error, the goal is, when user click STOP, to webdriver close, thanks :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WindowsFormsApp19
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private object webDriver;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ChromeDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();


           
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i=1; i<=100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                sum = sum + i;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
                Thread.Sleep(50000);


                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                    return;


                }

            }
            e.Result = sum;

        }

        public void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";


        }

        public void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          if(  e.Cancelled)
            {
                
                label1.Text = "Operation stopped ";
               }
          

          else if (e.Error != null)
            {

                label1.Text = e.Error.ToString();

            }

            else
            {

                label1.Text = "100% Completed";
            }

        }

        public void Startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {


                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        public void Stopbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {

                backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
               
              


            }
        }

       
    }
}
```

Comment: > with STOP button it shows me error

You mention that it shows an error... What is the error?
This might help debug your issue.

Comment: HI @MikeSmith, thanks for the question,  I just tried to put into :   public void Stopbutton_Click   webDriver.Quit()  , but  get error, I do not how to tell to script when user click stop button to stop and webdriver too, with this code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message and stack trace.